# Trying to open a file in another computer using Android studio which contains GIF but taking ages to build

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have moved over an Android studio file to another computer using a USB stick. However I'm having some issues. Its taking ages to build for some reason. It gets stuck when trying to download a GIF library. Its been trying to download for the past 20 minutes. I have tried opening it again, and still takes ages to open. It opens perfectly fine on the original

[image: Here is the image of what it is trying to download] computer.